# Error The following features required to run Godot projects on the Web are missing: Cross Origin Isolation, SharedArrayBuffer

Tags: godot, godot4

I exported the godot project to HTML5 and after uploading to itch.io I got the error `Error The following features required to run Godot projects on the Web are missing: Cross Origin Isolation - Check web server configuration (send correct headers) SharedArrayBuffer - Check web server configuration (send correct headers)`

I tried to export the project with different settings but still got 1 result.

Comment: See: https://itch.io/t/2025776/experimental-sharedarraybuffer-support

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the settings page of your game on itch under "embed options", you need to check `SharedArrayBuffer` Support

[image: Screenshot]